# How to properly use ExtensionManager and ExtensionHandler implementing classes

Tags: java, spring, broadleaf-commerce

- Broadleaf uses ExtensionManager class implementing InvocationHandler to extend functionalities (via extensionHandlers) and provide some sort of hooks (eg. first try extensionManager invocation of method and if it's not handled then proceed normally) to change framework classes behaviour without need to extend them and override methods.
- My first question is what is motivation behind this aproach if polymorfism is whole paradigm addressing this problem? What are benefits ?
- Secondly if I'm going to use it what is correct way to do that?
- For example I tried to extend AbstractInventoryServiceExtensionHandler and override methods (because broadleaf 5.0.1 has a bug in InventoryServiceImpl regarding CHECK_QUANTITY InventoryType in retrieveQuantitiesAvailable method)
- Next I extended InventoryServiceExtensionManager and try to register that extensionHandler with overidden methods
- In the moment of invocation of method in question - I got error on getProxy() method invoked on extensionManager saying ClassCastException from Proxy.toString() and handlers List is emtpy althought I registered handler ?
- In the end I simply extended InventoryServiceImpl and corrected the bug, which solved my problem but left me with above mentioned questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My first question is what is motivation behind this aproach if polymorfism is whole paradigm addressing this problem? What are benefits ?

This allows multiple "modules" (plugins) in the Broadleaf ecosystem to modify behavior at runtime (by registering themselves) rather than at compile time. It's a looser coupling. Also, things like polymorphism break down if you need the modify the same place in code multiple times (at that point you'd need multi-inheritance)

> Secondly if I'm going to use it what is correct way to do that?

Based on what you've said, you should never need to extend the extension *manager* but instead only the extension *handler*. The handler should then register itself with the manager. Here's an example:

```
@Component
public class MyInventoryExtensionHandler extends AbstractInventoryServiceExtensionHandler {

    @Resource
    protected InventoryServiceExtensionManager extensionManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
         extensionManager.registerHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public ExtensionResultStatusType retrieveQuantitiesAvailable(Collection<Sku> skus, Map<String, Object> context, ExtensionResultHolder<Map<Sku, Integer>> result) {
        ...
        ...
        return ExtensionResultStatusType.HANDLED;
    }
}
```

> For example I tried to extend AbstractInventoryServiceExtensionHandler and override methods (because broadleaf 5.0.1 has a bug in InventoryServiceImpl regarding CHECK_QUANTITY InventoryType in retrieveQuantitiesAvailable method)

What was the bug?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get started with demo site on 5.0.1 version and discover few bugs. First this one - if it's check quantity inventory type, sku inventory map in that method don't get populated with available quantities if it's not null. That results with 0 available quantity and you can't add product into cart because well 0 < 1.

Comment: Secondly - today I had problems with adding new page in admin. After hour of debugging I realize that PageImpl don't have auditable field any more (on 4.0 version it has) and it fails in AuditableListener where it tries to get that field throught reflection, and without checking  calls methods on it which results in NullPointerException.

Comment: Am I missing something or are those really bugs? I ask because I need to fix them and before doing that I want to be sure that I have correct working version.

Comment: Sounds like not a bug; if the inventory type is "check quantity" and you have no quantity set... seems like that should equate to zero.

Comment: If you don't want to actually check quantity, change the inventory type to null or ALWAYS_AVAILABLE.

Comment: Ok, it's not the case. There is quantity set, I set it to 50 in admin.  But in that method, there is only one if - if it's null put zero, there is no else condition to actually put quantity (if it's not null) for that sku. Therefore it' impossible to put product in cart with check quantity inventory type. Do we understand each other ? I can send you mail or open issue on broadleaf forum.